# JuJu Controllers

Tags: juju, remote

I have a simple question.

I saw that juju controller can host multiple models but, in which scenario do we need more than one JuJu controller ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some scenarios it might be that you already have a google cloud environment and a AWS cloud for example. If you want to use both environments you will need to bootstrap a controller for each different cloud Environment. It is very usefull when you can switch between controllers once you realise there are some limitations on each type of cloud.

#### example:

- Aws does not support LXD containers so you can have your juju environment there if you don't need any LXD containers. If you really need LXD for some of your applications you could then bootstrap a second controller on Google CE to get that working

Besides the differences between the clouds it might be that your Google CE limits your amount of cores and that you've reached the limit of the amount of available cores. If you still have another cloud with some cores available, you can bootstrap a second controller for that cloud. In that way you don't have to expand your Google CE and you can still deploy charms in a new model on a new controller.

You can then easily switch between your controllers by using the `juju switch`  command

Answer (score 0):

Our use is a little simpler.  We have a local pool of end-of-lifed servers that are provisioned using MaaS, with a juju controller.  When our jobs before larger than the local pool can handle, or when there is resource contention between different groups, we spin up AWS systems to handle the overflow.